Examples of Confidence Intervals in Input Data
I am researching possible ways to efficiently train models that have to deal with confidence intervals in input data. In the example below, the feature has expected values of 15 and 21, respectively, which correspond to intervals of [11, 19] and [13, 24], where the lower and upper bounds of the values are given.



DateTime
Feature_Low
Feature
Feature_High




01.01.2024
11
15
19


01.02.2024
13
21
24



Alternatively, the confidence intervals may be given like this:



DateTime
Feature
Feature_Interval




01.01.2024
15
11-19


02.01.2024
21
13-24



I want to train a model that would make predictions into the future based on TimeSeries data and spit out features alongside with confidence intervals; however, I cannot find any resources that might have done anything similar. All I find deals with the output data having confidence intervals and not the input data that is being fed into the model.
This is an example of a dataset on Kaggle that has such data with confidence intervals, but there are no connected .ipynb notebooks that utilize machine learning models, only data analysis is given.
The only similar question on stackexchange I have been able to find is left unanswered.
I have researched a bit into Bayesian Neural Networks that deal with probabilistic distributions, which appears to be what I need, but it doesn't take confidence intervals as inputs either.
MAIN QUESTION: Is there any research on this topic I could further look into? I am looking for examples of models that were trained on features with confidence intervals.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
